# Design Research: Interactive graphic following mouse pointer on website

Tags: website-design, javascript, interaction

Doing some more visual design technique research. Nikita Nikiforov shows a very interesting visual feature on his website [Nikita Nikiforov](https://nikitanikiforov.it/).

See the `.gif` below or visit the website to see it in action.

[image: Nikita Nikiforov Web Design]

How might this be achieved? Being part graphic design, part web design related, this question might also need to be posted in the [stackoverflow community](https://stackoverflow.com/), but I'd like to try here first.

(No stealing of intellectual property intended, all credit goes of course to the original designer, I'm merely interested in broadening my horizon in regards to visual techniques)

Comment: This is not a design question. As the answer is use a javascript mouse handler. And as such implementing this most decidedly is in the realm of  stackoverflow. If you want to have an answer to this you should i.dicate your proficency level as now this question seems to ask a quite broad question.

Comment: @joojaa You're right. I'll move over to stackoverflow with this whole matter, thanks for pointing me the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site is using an open source vector graphics scripting framework called [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/):

[image]

As you mentioned, a more in-depth discussion on how to achieve the effect you're looking for will be more suitable for the Stackoverflow Community since it will involve a fair amount of coding.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this already helps, I wasn't aware of paper.js at all. I'm moving on with this question to stackoverflow now.